# PUT service method example?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

I feel like an idiot for asking but I know how to build a client side PUT request I also know how to create the operation contract for it but I dont actually know what to do for the service?

For instance if I was to `POST` student information I would do this:

```
    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        students.Add(student);
    }
```

But for an update or PUT I dont see anything when I type students, there isnt anything that looks like it could be it?

I know that I would first have to find the student of which I want to update, which would be set by the studentID, then I would want a string for whatever I would want to update. Apart from add or remove I dont really know how to achieve "updating". Has anyone got any example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the student as a parameter

```
public void UpdateStudent(Student student)
{
   var findStudent = students.Where(s => s.studentID == student.studentID).FirstOrDefault();

   if(findStudent != null)
   {
        ///update findStudent values with student values --- like
        findStudent.Name = student.Name;  

   }

}
```

Comment: Hey Anurag thanks for your answer, I know how to do what you said its the actual update part is it just Add again? I take it there is no such thing as `students.Update`?

Comment: What is the container type of students?

Comment: It is just an example.  I do not know what fields your `student` type has.  I was guessing that it had Name

Comment: actually findStudent. does not show FirstName or LastName from the list students?